# Is there any relationship between the wording in [cpp.pre]/7 and its example?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[cpp.pre]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.pre#7):

> The preprocessing tokens within a preprocessing directive are not
> subject to macro expansion unless otherwise stated.
>
> [Example 2: In:
>
> ```
> #define EMPTY
> EMPTY   #   include <file.h>
> ```
>
> the sequence of preprocessing tokens on the second line is not a
> preprocessing directive, because it does not begin with a # at the
> start of translation phase 4, even though it will do so after the
> macro EMPTY has been replaced. — end example]

Comment: Yeah, looks like an unrelated example since the section is talking about expansion once a directive has been identified, not about how directives are identified. Better example would be `#define INC include` and then `#INC <vector> /* not a valid preprocessor directive */`

Comment: @RaymondChen That's exactly what I was thinking. Thank you.